# wkhtmltoimage make sharpen screenshots

Tags: wkhtmltoimage

It works. Make screenshots. But make it like any sharpen artefacts. Why? Maybe because wkhtmltoimage running without X? Where try get information? How to smooth screenshot via wkhtmltoimage?

This Firefox and Chromium 800x420: http://s18.postimg.org/xff896gsp/Screenshot_10.png

And this wkhtmltoimage 800x420:http://s9.postimg.org/auikf44st/Screenshot_11.png

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Im used: wkhtmltoimage 0.10.
Trying use newest version: wkhtmltoimage 0.12 - it works, images not sharpen, but failed stretch background images (-webkit-background-size: cover).

And perfect works: wkhtmltoimage 0.11 (static library amd64)